# TypeError: Target is not a typed array constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, meteor, runtime-error

The application is built using Meteor (version 2.2)

The error only occurs in production build in Firefox Mobile and Safari Instagram Browser (during loading of the application).
I cannot tell when the error started to occur but I've tested older versions of the application dated a couple of months ago.

I have also tested several versions of Firefox Mobile, so I assume the error is related to incorrect bundling or because of a corrupted Meteor package.

Has anyone come across such an error? What might be the cause? I've run out of ideas on where to look for it.

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvTUX.png)

[Screenshot from the local environment - initially the error comes from the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWCq5.png)

[Line 2759 - basically the code of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRv77.png)

[The line 2600 that throws the TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWsWi.png)

[Throw TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxL6a.png)

Comment: Unfortunately there is absolutely no way to help with so little information. The code at the address listed in the image is the entirety of your meteor application which is minified. The screen shot shows a stack trace with lines 5, 533, and 2600. The issue is that because of the minification, line 5 is meteor's module runtime, line 533 is all of your application specific code, and 2600 is the entire core-js module. I would recommend trying to reproduce the issue in a dev environment to get a better stack trace to determine the origin point of the error.

Comment: Run your project with `meteor run --production` to see locally where is the error.  With this parameter, the Meteor will minify the code locally. Can be some lib or your own code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey Juri, if you run this app in development you can use [firefox mobile](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/about_colon_debugging/index.html) or [chrome mobile](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) and use their remote debugging techniques to find the error in dev mode:

Comment: @KellyCopley That's the issue. It only happens in the production build. Dev environment works just fine. I've had issues before with core-js and Firefox/Safari Mobile, I had to add polyfill. But now I don't really have any more info.

Comment: @Jankapunkt as mentioned, unfortunately, the error occurs only in the production build. I have tried Firefox debug tools also.

Comment: @RicardoAragão I have updated the post with screenshots from the local environment.